# What is the sucker thingy called that can attach to smooth surfaces

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I can't even find a picture of it because I don't know what to search for. It's a circular rubber foot that attaches typically to glass, by creating a little vacuum when you press it onto the surface. What's it called?

Comment: Yep, the common form is a "suction cup".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called a **suction cup**. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suction_cup):

> A suction cup, also known as a sucker, is a device or object that uses the negative fluid pressure of air or water to adhere to nonporous surfaces, creating a partial vacuum.

Attribution: "Suction Cup." Wikipedia. February 28, 2018. Accessed April 05, 2018. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suction_cup.

Answer (score 1):

It is called a cup.

The flexible version is a suction cup.